# Component shows previous data when mount for fractions of seconds

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am developing an app named "GitHub Finder".

I am fetching the date in App component using async function and pass these function to User component as props and I call these functions in useEffect.

The problem is here, when I goto user page for second time it shows previous data which I passed in props from App component and then it shows loader and shows new data.

Here is App component code where I am fetching date from APIs and passing to User component through props.

```
// Get single GitHub user
  const getUser = async (username) => {
    setLoading(true);

    const res = await axios.get(
    `https://api.github.com/users/${username}?client_id=${
     process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${
     process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`
  );
    setUser(res.data);
    setLoading(false);
  }
  // Get user repos
  const getUserRepos = async (username) => {
    setLoading(true);

    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos? 
       per_page=5&sort=created:asc&client_id=${
       process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${
       process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`
     );

    setRepos(res.data);    
    setLoading(false);
   }`
```

**User component code**.

```
  useEffect(() => {
        getUser(match.params.login);
        getUserRepos(match.params.login);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
   }, []);
```

I've recorded a video, so you guys can easily understand what I am trying to say.
[Video link](https://www.loom.com/share/a14bc5fe942a4c4e81a420022168a16d)

[Check live app](https://github-finder-d467b.firebaseapp.com/)

How can I solve this problem?

Thank in advance!

Comment: I think when you click the button to go back to search, you should clear the current state.

Comment: Thanks for comment @Colin Ricardo. I have used this option but it does not work.

Comment: Can you make a CodeSandbox? I can take a look.

Comment: You can check github repo: https://github.com/xamQrexii/github-finder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happens in the app :

1. When the App component is rendered the first time, the state is `user={}` and `loading=false`
2. When you click on a user, the `User` component is rendered with props `user={}` and `loading=false`, so no spinner is shown and no data.
3. After the `User` component is mounted, the `useEffect` hooks is triggered, `getUser` is called and set `loading=true` (spinner is shown) then we get the user data `user=user1` and set `loading=false` (now the user data is rendered)
4. When you go back to search page, the app state is still `user=user1` and `loading=false`
5. Now when you click on another user, the `User` component is rendered with props `user=user1` and `loading=false`, so no spinner is shown and the data from previous user is rendered.
6. After the `User` component is mounted, the `useEffect` hooks is triggered, `getUser` is called and set `loading=true` (spinner is shown) then we get the user data `user=user2` and set `loading=false` (now the new user data is rendered)

One possible way to fix this problem :

- instead of using the `loading` boolean for the `User` component, inverse it and use `loaded`
- When the `User` component is unmounted clear the user data and the loaded boolean.

App component:

```
 const [userLoaded, setUserLoaded] = useState(false);

 const getUser = async username => {
    await setUserLoaded(false);

    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://api.github.com/users/${username}?client_id=${
        process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID
      }&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`
    );

    await setUser(res.data);
    setUserLoaded(true);
  };

  const clearUser = () => {
    setUserLoaded(false);
    setUser({});
  };

<User
  {...props}
  getUser={getUser}
  getUserRepos={getUserRepos}
  repos={repos}
  user={user}
  loaded={userLoaded}
  clearUser={clearUser}
/>
```

User component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getUser(match.params.login);
    getUserRepos(match.params.login);
    // eslint-disable-next-line

    return () => clearUser();
  }, []);

  if (!loaded) return <Spinner />;
```

You can find the complete code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github-finder-yynky)

Comment: Thanks buddy! It really works. I've a question:
When I use ComponetDidMount() it works with my logic but when I use useEffect() which is alternate of CDM but it does not work!!

Comment: There is a difference between CDM and useEffect. From the docs useEffect "Unlike componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate, the function passed to useEffect fires **after** layout and paint", for CDM "You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen **before** the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state."

Comment: There is another hook `useLayoutEffect ` that fires like CDM "useLayoutEffect fires in the same phase as componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate. However, we recommend starting with useEffect first and only trying useLayoutEffect if that causes a problem."

Answer (score 0):

Please make your setUser([]) empty at the start of getUser like this:

```
  const getUser = async (username) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setUser([]);

    const res = await axios.get(
    `https://api.github.com/users/${username}?client_id=${
     process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${
     process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`
  );
    setUser(res.data);
    setLoading(false);
  }
```